# How to iterate the split data using robot framework. I have 3 scenarios to validate based on this functionality

Tags: validation, robotframework

```
       Profile User
        ${profile_user}     ${profile_domain}=      Split String       ${username}    separator=@
        ${profile_user}=    Replace String          ${profile_user}    -              ${SPACE}
        ${profile_user}=    Convert To Uppercase    ${profile_user}
        [Return]            ${profile_user}
    
    # Both are equal , but still return None    
    Validate Owner field
        [Arguments]            ${owner}
        ${text}=               Convert To Uppercase      ${owner}
        ${profile_user}=       Profile User
        log                    ${text}
        ${status}=             should contain      ${profile_user}      ${text}
        [Return]               ${status}
    
    # We can validate awp text
    Validate softwarebundle field
        [Arguments]            ${softwarebundle}      ${bundle_id}
        ${bundle_id}=          Convert To Uppercase      ${bundle_id}
        ${bundle_id}=          Replace String            ${bundle_id}    -              ${SPACE}
        ${status}=             should contain       ${softwarebundle}         ${bundle_id}
        [Return]               ${status}
    
    **# I want to validate weather complete date is matching with the same format  using current date**
    Validate Create time
        [Arguments]               ${expdate}
        ${UI_Creation_time}=      Set Variable             ${text}
        ${CurrentDate} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%m/%d/%Y
        Log    ${CurrentDate}
        ${status}=                should contain           ${text}      ${CurrentDate}
        [Return]                  ${status}
        
        
        
****Data:
${username}=    UAT APP USER
${owner}=       UAT APP USER
${softwarebundle}=          awp 9.4 se      
${bundle_id}=               awp
${expdate}=    06/30/2020 6.40PM****
```

**Using above data , we should get the status as True for every function, then only i can proceed with another functionality.

For 2nd function i am trying to validate complete data using should be equal keyword in framework, But it is returns None
For 3rd function i am using Should contain keyword. For 1st variable we are getting data as 'awp ss wrd' , here i want to validate 'aws' is available or not , still condition fails
For 4th , i want to validate date with the format of '06/30/2020 6.40 PM', Here i tried by validating only date without time, still it returns None.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can paste the entire robot file with valid sections - Variables, Test Cases, Keywords, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get return status of variable true false please try to use this keyword ***`Run Keyword And Return Status`***

```
${status}=      Run Keyword And Return Status   should contain      ${profile_user}      ${text}
```

the expected result will be True and False.
[Document](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status)